# Extbase, Uncaught TYPO3 Exception. Flush system cache solves is for a while

Tags: typo3, extbase

Site works fine. Suddenly it will through an error. When clicking "flush system cahce" the error will go away for a some time. Anything from minuttes to severaæ hours.

> Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1247602160:
>   Unknown column 'tx_my_domain_model_formular.rel_formular' in 'where
>   clause' |
>   TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Exception\SqlErrorException
>   thrown in file
>   /webserver/typo3/src/6.2.15/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbBackend.php
>   in line 862.

It is correct that the columns does not exist. But how to preceed in finding the error after this? Where is the sql generated that causes the site to crash?

UPDATE

A check "myParentObj->getChildObj instanceof myChildObjClass" used to work just fine. After changing myParent model to lazy load the ChildObj, then the class of childObj changed from childObjClass to a lazyLoadClass... I am not sure but I guess that is in turns somewhere somehow caused the core error seen in the log.

How to investigate further I simply cannot work out. Eg. store all DB calls in a file og DB to analyze after the error occours.

Answer (score 2):

**First**

Please take time to write a good question. For a good question you'll get a good answer. It doesn't have to be perfect (not everyone is a native english speaker) but please reread your question.

**Answer**

If all fields are defined correctly, just run a DB compare from within the installtool.
If not, you need to define the DB-fields in your extension correctly.

Comment: Yes, maybe I may have been unclear. DB is just fine. As written tx_my_domain_model_formular.rel_formular does not exist (and should not exist). So I am puzzled why the log say there is an error it in.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your own extension? When doing the query that triggers the error you could call execute(true) to generate the actual SQL statement and debug from there.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that one. execute(true).